# Why isn't my activity showing?

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

Im trying to display a Spinner and a TextView, the app runs but with a blank screen. 
This my Java code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by ????? on 4/11/2015.
 */
public class CarSelectionActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_car_screen);

        Spinner _make_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.make_spinner);
        String[] spinnerArray= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.make_array);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        _make_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

}
```

This is my XML Layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Spinner Dropdown"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="#ff5500"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:popupBackground="#FFFF99"
        android:id="@+id/make_spinner"
        />




</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.omnination.ossusum.gallonator" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".CarSelectionActivity"
            android:label="Gallonator" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Manifest has code for my maps fragment but i'm not testing that yet.

Comment: and you xml layout file is called `new_car_screen.xml`?

Comment: yes, later in the process im ganna change the naming

Comment: `android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"` is adding a new id instead of using the existing one but it should throw an error not a blank screen

Comment: @zgc7009 android is quite lenient to this type of mistake.

The textview has a white text color, the spinner is a more interesting case.

Comment: For some reason i had the feeling it had to do with my manifest.

Comment: he means "+id" is used in id only for the first time, to create it in the R.id file, when you refer to it further you use just "@id/textView1".

Comment: ahh okay ill make note of that for later projects.

Comment: If you change textview's text color to black, will you see at least textview?

Comment: nope, doesn't show any difference

Comment: in the visual layout editor, do you see your layout?

Comment: yes. It actually looks exactly how i want it too in the visual layout editor

Comment: try launching it in debug mode, set a breakpoint somewhere after `setContentView()` and have a look at `this` properties, it should have something about a layout attached, mb it gives some clue.

Comment: im not good with the debugger but it isnt showing anything that wouldnt be there otherwise.

Comment: you are right, but otherwise I can't think of any other reasons why this is happening, unless you attach `R.layout.new_car_screen`, but actually edit a different file, something like `activity_carselection.xml`.

Comment: ima try to start over

Comment: To help debug the issue, use elimination, to narrow it down. e.g. Use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout, Set the the text in the text view explicitly in the xml. Log the output of spinner array to check that it actually contains values.

Comment: Can you post your `R.array.make_array` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an issue in this line ;-

android:orientation="vertical"

Relativelayout-->  you can`t add orientation attribute to it. romove this line

Comment: Ive deleted this line of code yet it still doesnt show anything

Comment: i have tried your code and works fine i think the orientation was the problem can you clean the project and rebuild it again.